# What is the fastest way to load data from Oracle using ADO?

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

I need to read millions of registers from an Oracle database using ADO. What parameters should be used in order to achieve the best performance?

Comment: Is this a one-time only job or will this happen many times? I'd just give it a try with `TADOQuery.CursorType := ctOpenForwardOnly`, it will probably perform as good as it's possible. If performance truly isn't satisfactory I'd look at some native connection components (to avoid the overhead of ADO).

Comment: You're best chance is not using ADO. Why do you need to read millions of record? To export them? To process them? There's a good chance you could do it without using ADO, which BTW is not one of the most performant db access library. You have also to optimize your query, and check the database setup also - the bottleneck may not be ADO, but the server I/O, database cache, etc. First identify what is slow, then improve it. Usually there are no FAST=TRUE parameters (© Tom Kyte).

Comment: I am already using ctOpenForwardOnly. And I will happen frequently since data is read and consolidated. Unfortunately, it is necessary to use ADO. I am curious about of CacheSize, LockType and ExecuteOptions.

Comment: What if you consolidate it in Oracle first, then export it? Any round-trip you can avoid improves your performance.

Comment: It is not possible since it is necessary many calculations/processing.

Comment: Oracle is a very rich environment. Besides PL/SQL, you can write stored procedures in Java, and even in C, if needed. Anyway a query with a result set large enough may require ad-hoc solutions - after the bottlenecks have been identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is faster to use the ADO _Recordset interface directly instead of use TADODataset. 
ADO is not very fast, and TADODataset needs to query the underlying _Recordset to determine the column types etc (ADO has safecall interfaces so quite some overhead for each function/property read, look at the generated assembly in the CPU view).
By using _Recordset directly I have optimized the loading of data into our own dataobjects with a factor 2 (lots of small queries). Maybe it is useful for much data too.

For large queries you could use "read only" "server side cursor" with "open forward" (with client side cursor are data is loaded and cached at the client)

Comment: I've used (some time ago, so I could be forgetting some details) ADO "firehose" cursors. I guess this is the same thing Andre is suggesting in this last suggestion? I set the cursor location to: adUseServer and past adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly when I opened the recordset.

Comment: I am using the same. I just in order to confirm if our choices are correct or can be improved somewhat.